# What's the meaning of 心を壊す?

Tags: meaning

So, I was reading this http://alfalfalfa.com/articles/161036.html and I wanted to know what was the meaning of "心を壊す". Is it "to damage one's mind"?

> ポケモンのぬいぐるみ、人の**心を壊す**

I couldn't find the meaning, so I was trying to guess...

Comment: `to damage one's mind` そうですね・・「心」というか「精神」が壊れたのかも・・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that post they are probably referring to something like 精神を壊す like chocolate mentioned. Because if you read the comments, the people have gone a little crazy with this toy...

Also if you do a google search, 心 is replaced with 精神 or 感情 so it doesn't seem to be used all that often and when it is, is used in the [context of stress](http://cause-of-psychosomatic.com/stress/). Similar examples could be: [心が病む・心が折れる](http://twilight-night.com/archives/942)

Loosely translated, it could be: "To lose one's mind", "to go crazy" etc.